# How to get timezone abbreviation instead of hours offset from strftime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know there are many timezones that share the same offsets from UTC/GMT.
When using strftime('%Z') it returns the offset in hours/minutes.

Does anyone know of a simple way to get a timezone as a 3 character timezone string eg. +0100 => CET

I have defined by own date format in my time_formats.rb initializer

`Time::DATE_FORMATS[:friendly_datetime] = '%A, %-d %B %Y at %H:%M %Z'`

This produces:
`Sunday, 11 January 2015 at 20:00 +0100`

I'd like the %Z (+0100) to be CET.
I thought about creating my own translation hash and using a proc on my custom time format.
I was kinda hoping there was a built in way or maybe a gem I don't know of.

Comment: `Time.now.strftime('%A, %-d %B %Y at %H:%M %Z')` in the console gives "Monday, 22 December 2014 at 16:45 MST" for me. Is this not what you are seeing?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy hmm, that's annoying in console it works `Monday, 22 December 2014 at 23:54 GMT` called on a DateTime object from activerecord in a view writes +0000 instead of GMT

Comment: Make sure you have capital `Z` and not small `z`. I get `-0700` when I use `%z` and `MST` with `%Z'. Versions: Rails - 4.2.0, ruby - 2.1.5

Comment: Yep, using %Z, then in my view using `@tournament.start_at.in_time_zone('Berlin').to_formatted_s(:friendly_datetime)`

Comment: I'm also seeing this in rails (getting offset not abbreviation when using capitalized %Z).  Did you find a fix?

Comment: I also saw this. Seems you can fix it by making the DateTime into a Time: `DateTime.current.strftime("%H:%m %Z") + " | " + DateTime.current.to_time.strftime("%H:%m %Z")  # => "08:12 +01:00 | 08:12 CET`

Comment: Same for me.
`%z` and `%Z` both gives `+0545` instead of 'NPT'.

Comment: I never found a fix.